# Mostrar apenas aplicativos instalados pelo usuário

Tags: android, lista, arraylist, packages

Bom amigos, estou desenvolvendo uma app para que o usuário compartilhe, faça backup .. de apps terceiros.
Conseguir criar uma lista onde mostra todos os app's. Acontece que eu não quero que apareça os aplicativos de sistema, quero que apareça apenas os que foram instalados pelo usuário.

```
List<App> apps = new ArrayList<>();

        /* Criar lista de aplicativos */
        final PackageManager pm = getActivity().getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> packages =  pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
        for (ApplicationInfo packageInfo : packages) {
            String name;
            /* Usar nome de pacote se o nome de etiqueta estiver vazio */
            if ((name = String.valueOf(pm.getApplicationLabel(packageInfo))).isEmpty()) {
                name = packageInfo.packageName;
            }
            Drawable icon = pm.getApplicationIcon(packageInfo);
            String apkPath = packageInfo.sourceDir;
            long apkSize = new File(packageInfo.sourceDir).length();

            apps.add(new App(name, icon, apkPath, apkSize));
        }

        /* Organizar aplicativos na ordem alfabética */
        Collections.sort(apps, new Comparator<App>() {
                @Override
                public int compare(App app1, App app2) {
                    return app1.getName().toLowerCase().compareTo(app2.getName().toLowerCase());
                }
            });

        RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.app_list);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        new GridLayoutManager(getActivity(), 2);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        AppAdapter appAdapter = new AppAdapter(getActivity(), apps);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(appAdapter);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Muito obrigado, espero que vocês me ajudem.

Answer (score 0):

Tente o seguinte:

```
    final List<ApplicationInfo> mAllApp = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
    final List<ApplicationInfo> instalados = new ArrayList<>(0);

    for(final ApplicationInfo app : mAllApp){
        if((app.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) == 0) {
            // 1. Aplicativo baixado do Google Play Store
            instalados.add(app);
        }
    }
```

[fonte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8784505/how-do-i-check-if-an-app-is-a-non-system-app-in-android)